# How to print all values in a vector except a vector with a certain name in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to print all the values in a vector except for a vector with a certain name.

```
capital <- c("Prague","Kairo", "Seoul")
names(capital)<-c("Czech","Egypt","Korea")
```

is my vector.

I want to print out everything except for "Korea" without using a loop. I tried:

```
capital[c("Czech","Egypt")]
```

which produces a correct value, but I'm not sure if this is the only way to do it.

The code should produce the output of `capital[c("Czech","Egypt")]` without any loops. I wasn't sure if this was the only way to do it or if the if statements could be used to produce the same output.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a couple of options using base R.

```
capital <- c("Prague","Kairo", "Seoul") 
names(capital)<-c("Czech","Egypt","Korea")

capital[which(capital != "Seoul")]

select_caps <- c("Prague","Kairo") 
capital[capital %in% select_caps]
```

Or, more directly:

```
capital[capital %in% c("Prague","Kairo")]
```

Either way, you get

```
Czech    Egypt 
"Prague"  "Kairo"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in several ways, If you know the index of the name you want to remove `"Korea"` you can use index number.

```
capital <- c("Czech","Egypt","Korea")
capital[-3]
```

*Remember vector index number start from 1

Or you can use logical condition,

```
capital <- c("Czech","Egypt","Korea")   
capital[capital != "Korea"]
```

Or using `%in%` operator you can do the same,

```
capital <- c("Czech","Egypt","Korea")
remove <- c("Egypt", "Korea")
capital[! capital %in% remove]
```